# Azure Queues vs Topics

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I am developing a website to be deployed in Azure. Right now I am using an Azure Queue to send emails to users. I am checking the Queue for received messages after each 60 seconds by sleeping the current Thread.

My problem is I do not want to wait the Thread and wait for 60 seconds, instead I want to trigger the message sending functionality when the Queue actually receives a message. I found the mechanism of [Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/) but I want to know whether I can implement the same Subscription mechanism with Azure Queues (without using Topics/Subscriptions). Is this possible? Can an Azure Queue listen to something so it can run only when a message is received to the Queue. I certainly don't want to sleep the Thread.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The question of Azure Queues supporting long-polling has been asked before - which is why I marked this as a duplicate.

Regarding thread-sleep: Not sure why you *certainly* don't want to sleep a thread to listen on a queue. It can be a separate thread, meaning you're not tying up other processes. And... as long as there are messages on the queue, you don't need to sleep between calls to `GetMessage()` - just keep reading until the queue is empty.

Also: Why wait 60 seconds? Start with 1 second, maybe exponential backoff to, say, 16 seconds, then stay there? Barely costs anything to check every few seconds (a penny per 100K transactions). This is a very common pattern, even with multiple role instances running.